# Do any major Christian traditions have documented ways of dealing with religious doubt?

Tags: faith, doubt

Many religions claim to be the only true religion, including most branches of Christianity. Among the major Christian traditions, are there any documented statements of faith that include the possibility that their own beliefs might not be the "one true religion"?  In other words, is there **any literature treating religious doubt** accepted in the tradition as *part of* the tradition, and not examples of individual cases of religious doubt?

If there is such literature, and if this point is covered within it, how do these major traditions view themselves in light of the "risk" involved if they were wrong in the claim to exclusive truth?

Comment: 1Co 15:16  For if the dead rise not, then is not Christ raised: 
1Co 15:17  And if Christ be not raised, your faith is vain; ye are yet in your sins. 
1Co 15:18  Then they also which are fallen asleep in Christ are perished. 
1Co 15:19  If in this life only we have hope in Christ, we are of all men most miserable.

Comment: @user4813 i asked this question to start off with [hope only in Christ](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16868)

Comment: Okay I've split out the first of what might be two main questions we could make out of your original material. I'm pretty sure the case studies you show are not going to get you anything constructive unless you were to take them one case at a time and really interested in Christianity's teaching on the issues, not your own world view. In the mean time I suggest we let this question run as is for now and then talk about how to get the second one (about historical reversals of positions, e.g. Catholic dogma renouncing previous dogma) later after we get a handle on this one. Savvy?

Comment: [standards of a believer involve suffering](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16870) this should answer your first previous point

Comment: do you want the other points answered as well?

Comment: **<Mod notice>:** I did some massive comment cleanup on anything that was related to the first version of this question. A lot of that was off topic: let's please remember that comments are not for debating issues involved but just for feedback _on the post_ in order to improve it (or in this case make it workable). On the other hand some of you had valuable advice along just those lines, but since I've nuked the context both out of the question and the other comments they were no longer of much use.

Comment: This is an interesting question in its own right. Thanks @caseyr547. At some point I'd be interested in how Christians / churches defend radical / unpopular social policy choices, given that their ideology **might not be true** after all. To take an extreme example, if the Inquisition had the humility to say "we might be wrong on cosmology", they would have had the prudence to imprison for life instead of burning at stake. There are lots of social policies advocated by Christians today that impact peoples' lives in **possibly** (but some would say **likely**) negative ways.

Comment: I'd say that it's always important for a group / organization to contemplate their own fallibility. Otherwise, the dangers of group think / fundamentalism / fanaticism are too real and too evil to be ignored. That's why I think this is an important question and issue (even though I see it doesn't make believers comfortable)

Comment: @caseyr547, I can't seem to comment on http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16870. If you were trying to address one of my questions, I didn't mean to blame the confession part. Instead, I blame the "strategy" of painting as sinful natural human desires and activities, in order to elicit "cycle of guilt behavior" (I feel guilty, I confess, I feel privileged by "forgiveness", I get even more caught up in the ideology, I "sin" again because it's really a natural impulse not a "sin", rinse, repeat). Perhaps I'll ask a separate question about "victimless sins".

Comment: @user4813 people feel guilt regardless of their status as believers. we primarily have the additional guilt of sin rather than the simple guilt caused by empathy. Everyone normal person feels I hurt you I empathize with your pain I feel guilty for causing you pain. We through our sins caused pain to to happen to Jesus so we feel guilt additionally when we add to the sufferings of Christ.

Comment: @user4813 its sorda funny my question was down voted more than yours and i wasn't even attacking christianity lol

Comment: @user4813 A question not being a good fit for this site is in no way an indication of whether "believers are comfortable" with it. Frankly the existence of this kind of question in real life doesn't make me uncomfortable in the slightest. Don't be too quick to  read an expected outcome into people's reactions.

Comment: @caseyr547 The downvotes typically don't have anything to do with whether you are "attacking Christianity" or not. Of course it's impossible to speak for everybody but I know that is not the metric used by most experienced people in this site. Future usefulness, suitability to the format, amount of prior research shown, and quality of the scope or framework given etc all play factors.

Comment: @caseyr547, regarding the additional burden due to "pain caused to Jesus", this is exactly what I was talking about. How do you know this is true (I suppose you haven't met Jesus's spirit like St Thomas)? Exactly, somebody told you so -- somebody who also never met Jesus. So it's all an ideology based not on rational derivation (like, say, Communism, which is harmful enough) but on a chain of "an old man told me so"'s.

Comment: @user4813 it doesn't matter that we can't prove that its true empirically. Even the most rational person does things which they cannot empirically justify to cause himself to feel good. Like I don't know why but swimming makes me feel good. If you fail to win a competitive swimming match you likewise are going to feel bad but that pain is limited and it doesn't outweigh the joys of swimming. Also if you swim a lot your body is going to be sore and you may experience actual pain but that doesn't stop you from swimming.

Comment: @user4813 religion like marriage is psychologically healthy even though it is associated with some suffering and stress.

Comment: @caseyr547, sure, religion makes some feel good. If you like to do guide your actions by the fear of causing pain to Jesus, not just others (or more importantly **yourself**), and it helps you reach hapiness, it's your choice. Where I have reservations is that it is taught to some from a young age, without giving them any alternatives, and it ends up not being a good fit and not bring hapiness, but misery. Well, at least the penalty for apostasy isn't death like in Islam, but still the visions of Christian hell are a powerful deterrent.

Comment: You are combining doctrine, dogma and individual beliefs in your question which makes it hard to answer. Perhaps you could split the question into documentation of the Church (its Dogma) that allows for the possibility of errancy, and the doctrine which is taught by its leaders, that questions the faith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Unitarian Universalism, but here are a few facts and references relevant to your question:

- It looks like contemporary Unitarian Universalists do not identify themselves with Christianity any more than with any other religion.
- Few, if any, Christian groups would consider individuals who hold the [beliefs](http://www.uua.org/beliefs/index.shtml) espoused by the UUA to be Christians.
- Originally, both Unitarians and Universalists -- separate groups until 1961 -- identified themselves as Christians ([UUA.org History page](http://www.uua.org/beliefs/history/index.shtml)).
- The "Quotes from Unitarian Universalists" page from [this](http://www.uuvisalia.org/spirit/quotes.html) UU congregation's site offers the following:

> "Cherish your doubts, for doubt is the attendant of truth. Doubt is the key to the door of knowledge; it is the servant of discovery. A belief which may not be questioned binds us to error, for there is incompleteness and imperfection in every belief. Doubt is the touchstone of truth; it is an acid which eats away the false. Let no one fear for the truth, that doubt may consume it; for doubt is the testing of belief. The truth stands boldly and unafraid; it is not shaken by the testing." - Robert T. Weston

- A number of individual UU church sites describe doubt as a "virtue" (Examples [here](http://www.sheridanuu.org/Presentations%20Folder/2010/Doubt-the%20essance%20of%20UU.pdf) and [here](http://uufsm.org/d7/content/doubt-uu-virtue)).

---

Edit: I would also suggest -- though I'm not sure what authorities to cite -- that a significant proportion of the subset of Christians who might generally be described as "well educated" in matters of the faith would consent that, implicit in the concept of "faith," there is some acknowledgement of the concept of doubt. Does that make sense? That is, the very statement, "I *believe* that x is true," can, to some hearers, demonstrate that the speaker admits of the possibility of error -- especially when contrasted with the similar, though not equivalent assertion, "x is true." The former is a statement about one's personal beliefs, qualified by the inclusion of a first person pronoun; the latter is formulated as a objective statement of fact.

I think we all, at some point in our respective lives, have "believed" statements which we later learned were untrue -- importantly, however, we have also "believed" in things that we later found to be factually accurate.

That may contribute something to explain the essential absence of formal references to doubt in historic Christian literature.

It's difficult to explain. I'm probably making it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Wikipedia summary: Unitarian was originally a particular brand of __non-trinitarianism__ that also did not believe in the godhood of Jesus. "In the past, the vast majority of members of Unitarian churches were Unitarians also in belief. Over time, however, some Unitarians and Unitarian Universalists moved away from the traditional Christian roots of Unitarianism." "Contemporary Unitarian Universalism espouses a pluralist approach to belief, whereby members may describe themselves as humanist, agnostic, deist, atheist, pagan, Christian, monotheist, pantheist, polytheist, or no label"

Comment: It sounds like UUA for some reason evolved towards acceptance (and embracing) of diversity. I wonder what caused them to take this spiritual path -- there are other Christian sects that deny Trinity, or the position of Jesus as an actual God.

Comment: When 99.9 out of 100(99.9%) accept Jesus as God, 0.1% cannot be termed as others?

Comment: What are you referring to? But in any case, an argument from majority is a pretty weak argument. "99.9%" of all human beliefs throughout the course of history were eventually proven wrong.

Comment: That was like top headline news on 1st april.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer, as it is the only one that actually addresses the question. I'm surprised there never came examples from Catholicism of Protestantism.

Comment: @jayyeshu, I really don't know that bit of news, and searching for it brings up nothing. Furthermore I can't tell what your position is :) Could you provide a link to a news article?

Answer (score 4):

> Many religions claim to be the only true religion, including most
>   branches of Christianity. Among the major Christian traditions, are
>   there any documented statements of faith that include the possibility
>   that their own beliefs might not be the "one true religion"? In other
>   words, is there any literature treating religious doubt accepted in
>   the tradition as part of the tradition, and not examples of individual
>   cases of religious doubt?

I think what is important to clarify is the difference between these two sentences above, which I will highlight by proposing two statements below:

1. **"We, as a faith community, include doubting we are correct in our belief as an official part of our belief, and so we announce these doubts in [doubt literature x]."**
2. **"We, as a faith community, understand that doubt is a normal human experience and that our adherents will likely, on occasion, doubt some or all of the tenets of our faith, and so we address this experience in [doubt literature x]."**

I am not aware of any "major Christian tradition" that has an accepted literature of the first type; that kind of institutionalized doubt is really not the purview of any religion, but is perhaps more the territory of scientists and skeptics.  It is unlikely religions would succeed as social phenomena if they made it clear in their official PR that "hey, we could be wrong on all this."* And in this I agree with Steve's answer below.

(*Though, humans being as strange as they are, it would be fascinating to be shown that I am wrong and that there *are* such traditions and statements.)

At best, some Christians may acknowledge that, while they are not *wrong*, other religions are "as correct as they are" in that they are all paths to the same union with the divine. I think Fr. Thomas Keating, for one, may be amenable to this, though he is not representative of the entirety of Catholicism by any means.

As regards statement (2), though:  In the Catholic tradition, there is something of a literature in this regards, yes.  The *Catechism of the Catholic Church*, for example, allows some leeway for a distinction they make between *voluntary doubt* and *involuntary doubt*:

> Voluntary doubt about the faith disregards or refuses to hold as true
>   what God has revealed and the Church proposes for belief. Involuntary
>   doubt refers to hesitation in believing, difficulty in overcoming
>   objections connected with the faith, or also anxiety aroused by its
>   obscurity. If deliberately cultivated, doubt can lead to spiritual
>   blindness. (CCC 2088)

Also, within the Catholic tradition there is also treatment of periods of spiritual torpor or feeling a lack of God's presence--sometimes referred to as "spiritual dryness" or also "acedia", and that may include doubts.  One often refers to St. John of the Cross's poem, *The Dark Night of the Soul* as a Catholic touchstone on this issue and that title has come to refer to the phenomenon itself.  In addition to St. John of the Cross, notable Catholic figures like Saint Thérèse of Lisieux, and Mother Theresa of Calcutta, who, it was found, claimed to have suffered from it for just over 50 years.

> If there is such literature, and if this point is covered within it,
>   how do these major traditions view themselves in light of the "risk"
>   involved if they were wrong in the claim to exclusive truth?

I am not aware of much in this regard, other than perhaps Pascal's Wager, which has been incorporated into the literature of various Christian apologists, in which he argues that the "risk" is something like finite inconvenience (as compared to the risk of infinite suffering).

Again, as Steve essentially pointed out, trying to promote religion by calling attention to the "what if we're wrong?" issue is sort of like trying to sell used cars by pointing out the puddles of transmission fluid all over the lot.

Comment: OK, interesting citations. I will upvote. I still prefer @PhilipSchaff's answer if I have to choose between these two (though your answer provides illuminating material)

Comment: On Point 1, the Witnesses at least do believe that their beliefs may be clarified in time ("the light shines ever brighter"), so they are treated as accurate, but open to revision. Also, they have some widely accepted theories not treated as definitive. This happens also in other religions; see for example the Catholic belief in Limbo: widely accepted as a reasonable belief, but never treated as definitive (until, eventually, it was definitively rejected). That could be seen as a form of Point 1: "We think this is likely to be true, but do not claim certainty."

Answer (score 2):

"Is there any literature treating religious doubt accepted in the tradition as part of the tradition?" That's an oxymoron, isn't it? "We believe Jesus is God, unless, of course, He isn't." That wouldn't be a statement of faith. Statements of faith are the rock-steady parts of the faith that they cling to as part of their identity.

Comment: I think that is probably oversimplifying what is a complex human phenomenon (religious belief).  Catholics, for example, have taken interest in the posthumously publicized case of Mother Theresa of Calcutta's long crisis of faith, and have, on some occasions, discussed it in the context of St. John of the Cross's "dark night of the soul".  Perhaps it could be argued that, at least *treating* doubt, at least in some fashion, actually lends credibility to a religion (as opposed to categorically dismissing doubt as though it is beneath the dignity of the adherents of that faith).

Comment: @chelonian, exactly the person I had in mind! I'm surprised no-one brought M. Theresa up before. But she was an individual (and she continue to preach while she had her own doubts).

Comment: @Steve: so you see no reason to doubt, and if there ever was any higher-up in the church who did see reasons (as I'm sure there were), you'd rather they kept it secret?

Comment: In any case, this answer disputes the premises of the question, instead of answering it. If the answer really is "no", say so. I'm going to accept the other answer, though I'm surprised no literature examples came from the Catholic or Protestant camp.

Comment: @user4813 Before you accept, maybe I'll try a shot at it.  A few major things out of Catholicism come to mind, amplifying what I wrote in the comment to Steve.

Comment: @Chelonian The OP wanted to know if there are any statements of faith regarding doubting their own God. That's what I addressed. Christian literature is full of addressing doubts of all kinds, including doubting God's love when undergoing hard times. But that's not what the OP is addressing.

Comment: @user4813 You might want to go into the atheist camp. It will be chock-full of people who were dissatisfied with their religion, gave in to their doubts and cast off God. But then 1 John 2:19 comes into play ("They went out from us because they were not of us"), and so they were never Christians in the first place.

Comment: If you read the actual question you will see that it was not at all about how to sweep your nagging feeling that you might be living a lie under the carpet of unquestioning belief. I thought I might see how folks deal with what seem to me fundamental objections. I also thought that rational people would welcome (even if a minority among a certain community) questioning their own belief. And actually answers from several posters show that they do both. I realize it's painful to confront reality and reciting verses is an easy way out of such situations.

Comment: @user4813 I was addressing this part: are there any documented statements of faith that include the possibility that their own beliefs might not be the "one true religion"? I"m sorry my answer was not that clear about it.